# Keyboard shortcut to move away from a full-screen remote desktop session

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

Using remote desktop in full-screen, what is the shortest way to move to another app?
(Without using the mouse, of course. I hate mice).

I currently use one of the following:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>del</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> (get to local machine's taskmgr), <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> (move to desired application), or:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>pause</kbd> (toggle remote-desktop to a window), <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Is there a shorter way?

Comment: In Windows 10, 1. Ctrl + Alt + Home ( moves the focus to the Remote Desktop Connection bar ), 2. Alt + Tab ( as if you were switching to another application on your local machine ) or you could use the alternative shortcut Win + M ( to minimize the RDP application ).

Answer (score 18):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>PAUSE</kbd>, then you may use <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Comment: You may also setup your RDP session to send Windows key combinations to your local computer instead of to the remote computer.
Do this by selecting options, "Local resources" and select "On the local computer" under "Keyboard" before connecting. You will not be able to use ALT-TAB on the remote oc.

Comment: Note my question: the 'ctrl-alt-pause, alt-tab' solution is there.

I'm looking for something shorter (only for full-screen mode, which is the only way I use remote desktop).

Answer (score 8):

Follow Berzerk's advice above to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to always run on the local computer. Then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PageUp</kbd> in the remote computer -- it works like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> inside of an RDP session.